# Implementing Logging in my Nodejs+React+Mongo app; How can I ensure it's scalable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, logging

I have a MERN web-app that I am implementing logging in.

The app is early in development, but I know that it will scale in the months and years to come.

#### So, what are the some best practices / things to look out when implementing logs?

*Specifically,*

- **How should I structure my log schema?**
- **Should I enforce log types, categories, etc ?**
- **Are there any npm-packages that can make my life easier?**

---

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**How should I structure my log schema?**

It depends on your need most of the time you need the logs to be structured in a
specific format so that later they can be transformed into some meaningful data.
Most of the time you need `username`, `ip`, `timestamp` and `action` to be logged.

**Should I enforce log types, categories, etc?**

Again depends but most of the time yes it should be done.

**Are there any npm-packages that can make my life easier?**

[winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) is a popular choice to implement logging in nodejs

You can do something like this:

```
import winston from 'winston';
import config from '../config/config';
import {LOGGER_LEVELS} from '../utils/app.constants';
const {combine, timestamp, label, printf, errors, metadata} = winston.format;

const myFormat = printf(({level, message, label, timestamp}) => {
  return `[${level}] ${label} ${timestamp} ${message}`;
}); // any format you desire

const transports: any = [];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  transports.push(
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'combined.log', // can save the logs to a file 
      level: LOGGER_LEVELS.INFO
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'error.log',
      level: LOGGER_LEVELS.ERROR
    })
  );
} else { // for development you want the console to be printed on terminal
  transports.push(
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.cli(), winston.format.splat())
    })
  );
}

const LoggerInstance = winston.createLogger({
  level: config.logs.level,
  levels: winston.config.npm.levels,
  format: combine(
    label({label: 'date:'}),
    timestamp({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    errors({stack: true}),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports
});

export default LoggerInstance;
```

and then wherever you need to use it simply create an instance of logger and you can use it.

```
LoggerInstance.log({
      level: LOGGER_LEVELS.INFO,
      message: <any_message>
    });
```

Comment: This is fantastic advise! Winston looks like a great starting point! Thanks!